# Play m4a file from document Directory

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer, nsfilemanager

I would to play an m4a file but I'm getting an error in the console and the file won't play.

**Console prints:**

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 2003334207.)

```
let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
print("File Location: ",url.path)

if(FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path)) {
   do {
       audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
       guard let player = audioPlayer else { return }

       player.prepareToPlay()
   } catch let error {
       print(error.localizedDescription)
   }

} else {
    print("file not found")
}
```

I tried URL like this:

```
let NoteUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Voice Note", withExtension: "m4a")
```

But I couldn't get it to play. Can someone help me to play m4a file by file's name? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the Documents folder to the audio player. Your code needs to append the specific filename to the Documents folder.

```
let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
let url = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("Voice Note.m4a")
```